# Combining a number of different tables of large size to create one 'universal table' without a primary key

Tags: sql-server, loops

I want to develop a query in SQL to create a 'universal table' that will include every column header that exists across all the individual product files.

Take the simplified version below as an example. There are six different column headers: A, B, C, D, E, F. We have three separate product files but none of these contain all six column headers.

```
                   A    C   D   F   
Product 1          55   100 20  40  

                   A    B   E       
Product 2          78   45  21      

                   B     C   D   E   F
Product 3          101   164 24  64  56
```

I want to create a single table that has all column headers and just includes blank fields or NULL values for products where the data is not available. This global table would look something like this:

```
                      A B   C   D   E   F
  Product 1          55     100 20      40
  Product 2          78 45          21   
  Product 3          101    164 24  64  56
```

My aim is to create a query which will output a table containing all policies from existing policy tables( for example tables such as SII_201703_U_EPIE_IMP and SII_201703_U_EPLE_IMP already exist, where EPIE and EPLE refer to the policy type and 201703 refers to the period in question. There are 65 of these files in total). I want to combine all 65 of them. They do not all contain the same column headings, however some do overlap. in total there is 180 distinct column headings over the 65 policies. i want my new table to contain all 180 headings and where a policy file does not contain a column heading return a NULL in the new table as seen in the simple example above.

Because there are 180 column headings and not just 6 i want to be able to create a string of the column headings ( as a query already exists outputting the columns 
SELECT DISTINCT COLUMN_NAME FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS WHERE 
TABLE_NAME LIKE '%201703%IMP';)
so i will not have to manually update them if they were to change between time periods.

Does this make my preferred outcome clearer?

I've already created a query whereby it casts NULL for values which don't exist but the way which i have constructed it make it quite monotonous if any changes were to occur to column headings etc.

Here is what i have come up with so far on a sample of 2 policies:

/*Returns table of all policies grouped by EB_UL_GRU_RP_SAVE with 180 column headings. % signifies the date in question i.e. 201703 is March 2017*/

```
SELECT POLICY_NUMBER
    , [RunNumber$]
    , SPCODE
    , MODEL_POINT
    , ACCIDENTAL_DEATH_CHARGE
    , ACCIDENTAL_INJURY_CHARGE
    , ACC_DEATH_REIN_CLAIMS
    , ACC_DEATH_REIN_COST
    , ALLOCATED_TO_FUND
    , ANNUAL_PREM
    , ANN_PREM_IF
    , ARF_DRAWDOWN_FEE
    , BEL_MASS_LAPSE_EVENT
    , BEL_MASS_LAPSE_EVENT_PER_POL_EXP
    , BID_OFFER_SPREAD_INCOME
    , BONUS_PROVISION
    , BONUS_PROV_CHANGE
    , CCC_ACORN_COST
    , CCC_CHARGE
    , CDC_ACORN_COST
    , CDC_CHARGE
    , CHANGE_NON_UNIT_RES
    , CHC_ACORN_COST
    , CHC_CHARGE
    , COMPANY_INCOME
    , COMPANY_OUTGO_BEL
    , COMP_CI_ACORN_COST
    , COMP_CI_CHARGE
    , COMP_CI_REIN_CLAIMS
    , COMP_CI_REIN_COST
    , CORE_CI_ACORN_COST
    , CORE_CI_CHARGE
    , CORE_CI_REIN_CLAIMS
    , CORE_CI_REIN_COST
    , CRITICAL_ILLNESS_CHARGE
    , CRIT_ILL_ACORN_COST
    , CRIT_ILL_EXP_REFUND
    , CRIT_ILL_REIN_CLAIMS
    , CRIT_ILL_REIN_COST
    , CURRENT_BONUS_PROV
    , CURRENT_BONUS_PROV_REL_MASS_LAPSE
    , CURRENT_COMMISSION
    , CURRENT_COMM_CLAWBACK
    , CURRENT_ON_DEATH
    , DEBT_DECREASE
    , DEBT_INCREASE
    , Cast(NULL AS INT) AS DELTA_SER3_NUR
    , DISC_NET_REIN_RECOVERABLE
    , DISC_PROF_A
    , DISC_PROF_B
    , DISC_PROF_BEL
    , DISC_PROF_BEL_22Y
    , DISC_PROF_BEL_EX_REIN
    , DISC_PROF_BEL_PP_EXP
    , DISC_PROF_BEL_PP_EXP_22Y
    , DISC_PROF_C
    , DISC_REN_EXP
    , E_VALUE_CMF
    , E_VALUE_DPT
    , E_VALUE_MF
    , E_VALUE_MGF
    , E_VALUE_TRACKER
    , FIELD_EXPENSE
    , FIELD_EXPENSE_CLAWBACK
    , FLAT_SERVICING_COMMISSION
    , FLAT_SERVICING_COMM_CLAWBACK
    , FR_FINANCING
    , FR_REPAYMENT
    , FSC_AMOUNT
    , FSC_CLAWBACK
    , FSC_PAID
    , FUNDS_POLICY_FEE
    , FUNDS_RENEWAL_EXPENSE
    , FUND_MAN_CHARGE_INCOME
    , FUND_START
    , GROSS_FUND_UNIT_GTH
    , GROSS_PROFIT
    , GROSS_PROFIT_BEL
    , GROSS_PROFIT_EX_REIN
    , GUARANTEED_ON_DEATH
    , HEAD_OFFICE_EXPENSE
    , HOSPITAL_CASH_CHARGE
    , HOSP_CASH_ACORN_COST
    , IC_PAID
    , IE_FIXED_FIELD
    , IE_FIXED_HO
    , INC_NAP_INCOME
    , INDEXATION_COMMISSION
    , INDEX_COMM_CLAWBACK
    , INDEX_NAP_INCOME
    , INFORCE
    , INFORCE_START_MTH
    , INVESTMENT_AMOUNT
    , INVESTMENT_GROWTH
    , INVESTMENT_GROWTH_BONUS_PROV
    , I_VALUE_CMF
    , I_VALUE_DPT
    , I_VALUE_MF
    , I_VALUE_MGF
    , I_VALUE_TRACKER
    , LAPSE_PROFIT
    , LIFE_COVER_ACORN_COST
    , LIFE_COVER_CHARGE
    , LIFE_COVER_REIN_CLAIMS
    , LIFE_COVER_REIN_COST
    , LOSS_MAKING_BEL_EX_EXP
    , LOSS_MAKING_BEL_INCL_EXP
    , MAN_CHARGE
    , MAN_CHRG_ON_BONUS_RES
    , Cast(NULL AS INT) AS MAN_CHRG_WAIVED_AFT_CAP
    , MASS_LAPSE_EXPENSE_SAVINGS
    , MASS_LAPSE_EXPENSE_SAVINGS_PC
    , MASS_LAPSE_EXPENSE_SAVINGS_PP
    , MONETARY_POLICY_FEE
    , NET_CURRENT_COMMISSION
    , NET_FLAT_SERVICING_COMMISSION
    , NET_FUND_GROWTH
    , NET_INDEXATION_COMMISSION
    , NET_REINSURANCE_RECOVERABLE
    , NET_REIN_FIN_RECOVERABLE
    , NET_RENEWAL_COMMISSION
    , NON_UNIT_RESERVE_PP
    , NUR_CHANGE
    , PEN_FEE_INCOME
    , PEN_FEE_RATE_PC
    , PERSONAL_ACCIDENT_CHARGE
    , PERS_ACC_ACORN_COST
    , POLICY_FEE_INCOME
    , POLICY_VALUE
    , PREMIUM_INCOME
    , PREM_LEVY
    , PROFITABLE_BEL_EX_EXP
    , PROFITABLE_BEL_INCL_EXP
    , RENEWAL_COMMISSION
    , RENEWAL_COMM_CLAWBACK
    , RENEWAL_EXPENSE
    , SCOR_PART2_PREMIUM
    , Cast(NULL AS INT) AS SER3_BONUS_ALLOC
    , Cast(NULL AS INT) AS SER3_BONUS_FUND_EXP
    , Cast(NULL AS INT) AS SER3_BONUS_FUND_MC
    , Cast(NULL AS INT) AS SER3_NUR_RELEASE
    , Cast(NULL AS INT) AS SOLV_MARG_IF
    , SUMS_AT_RISK_IF
    , SUM_REINSURED
    , SURG_CASH_ACORN_COST
    , SURRENDER_PENALTY
    , TAX_RELIEF_EXPENSES
    , TOTAL_ACORN_COST
    , TOTAL_ACORN_COST_POLICIES_IN_DEBT
    , TOTAL_EXPENSE_AND_COMMISSION
    , TOTAL_EXPERIENCE_REFUND
    , TOTAL_REINSURANCE_CLAIMS
    , TOTAL_REINSURANCE_COST
    , TOTAL_RISK_CHARGES
    , TOT_EXPENSE
    , UNIT_LIABILITY_START
    , UNIT_RES_IF
    , V_POLICY_VALUE
    , WAIVER_ACORN_COST
    , WAIVER_CHARGE
    , WEIGHTED_INFORCE
    , WEIGHTED_INFORCE_MASS_LAPSE
FROM   [SII_%_U_EFIE_IMP] 

UNION ALL

SELECT POLICY_NUMBER
    , [RunNumber$]
    , SPCODE
    , MODEL_POINT
    , ACCIDENTAL_DEATH_CHARGE
    , ACCIDENTAL_INJURY_CHARGE
    , ACC_DEATH_REIN_CLAIMS
    , ACC_DEATH_REIN_COST
    , ALLOCATED_TO_FUND
    , ANNUAL_PREM
    , ANN_PREM_IF
    , ARF_DRAWDOWN_FEE
    , BEL_MASS_LAPSE_EVENT
    , BEL_MASS_LAPSE_EVENT_PER_POL_EXP
    , BID_OFFER_SPREAD_INCOME
    , BONUS_PROVISION
    , Cast(NULL AS INT) AS BONUS_PROV_CHANGE
    , CCC_ACORN_COST
    , CCC_CHARGE
    , CDC_ACORN_COST
    , CDC_CHARGE
    , CHANGE_NON_UNIT_RES
    , CHC_ACORN_COST
    , CHC_CHARGE
    , COMPANY_INCOME
    , COMPANY_OUTGO_BEL
    , COMP_CI_ACORN_COST
    , COMP_CI_CHARGE
    , COMP_CI_REIN_CLAIMS
    , COMP_CI_REIN_COST
    , CORE_CI_ACORN_COST
    , CORE_CI_CHARGE
    , CORE_CI_REIN_CLAIMS
    , CORE_CI_REIN_COST
    , CRITICAL_ILLNESS_CHARGE
    , CRIT_ILL_ACORN_COST
    , CRIT_ILL_EXP_REFUND
    , CRIT_ILL_REIN_CLAIMS
    , CRIT_ILL_REIN_COST
    , CURRENT_BONUS_PROV
    , CURRENT_BONUS_PROV_REL_MASS_LAPSE
    , CURRENT_COMMISSION
    , CURRENT_COMM_CLAWBACK
    , CURRENT_ON_DEATH
    , DEBT_DECREASE
    , DEBT_INCREASE
    , Cast(NULL AS INT) AS DELTA_SER3_NUR
    , DISC_NET_REIN_RECOVERABLE
    , DISC_PROF_A
    , DISC_PROF_B
    , DISC_PROF_BEL
    , DISC_PROF_BEL_22Y
    , DISC_PROF_BEL_EX_REIN
    , DISC_PROF_BEL_PP_EXP
    , DISC_PROF_BEL_PP_EXP_22Y
    , DISC_PROF_C
    , DISC_REN_EXP
    , E_VALUE_CMF
    , E_VALUE_DPT
    , E_VALUE_MF
    , E_VALUE_MGF
    , E_VALUE_TRACKER
    , FIELD_EXPENSE
    , FIELD_EXPENSE_CLAWBACK
    , FLAT_SERVICING_COMMISSION
    , FLAT_SERVICING_COMM_CLAWBACK
    , FR_FINANCING
    , FR_REPAYMENT
    , FSC_AMOUNT
    , FSC_CLAWBACK
    , FSC_PAID
    , FUNDS_POLICY_FEE
    , FUNDS_RENEWAL_EXPENSE
    , FUND_MAN_CHARGE_INCOME
    , FUND_START
    , GROSS_FUND_UNIT_GTH
    , GROSS_PROFIT
    , GROSS_PROFIT_BEL
    , GROSS_PROFIT_EX_REIN
    , GUARANTEED_ON_DEATH
    , HEAD_OFFICE_EXPENSE
    , HOSPITAL_CASH_CHARGE
    , HOSP_CASH_ACORN_COST
    , IC_PAID
    , IE_FIXED_FIELD
    , IE_FIXED_HO
    , INC_NAP_INCOME
    , INDEXATION_COMMISSION
    , INDEX_COMM_CLAWBACK
    , INDEX_NAP_INCOME
    , INFORCE
    , INFORCE_START_MTH
    , INVESTMENT_AMOUNT
    , INVESTMENT_GROWTH
    , INVESTMENT_GROWTH_BONUS_PROV
    , I_VALUE_CMF
    , I_VALUE_DPT
    , I_VALUE_MF
    , I_VALUE_MGF
    , I_VALUE_TRACKER
    , LAPSE_PROFIT
    , LIFE_COVER_ACORN_COST
    , LIFE_COVER_CHARGE
    , LIFE_COVER_REIN_CLAIMS
    , LIFE_COVER_REIN_COST
    , LOSS_MAKING_BEL_EX_EXP
    , LOSS_MAKING_BEL_INCL_EXP
    , MAN_CHARGE
    , MAN_CHRG_ON_BONUS_RES
    , Cast(NULL AS INT) AS MAN_CHRG_WAIVED_AFT_CAP
    , MASS_LAPSE_EXPENSE_SAVINGS
    , MASS_LAPSE_EXPENSE_SAVINGS_PC
    , MASS_LAPSE_EXPENSE_SAVINGS_PP
    , MONETARY_POLICY_FEE
    , NET_CURRENT_COMMISSION
    , NET_FLAT_SERVICING_COMMISSION
    , NET_FUND_GROWTH
    , NET_INDEXATION_COMMISSION
    , NET_REINSURANCE_RECOVERABLE
    , NET_REIN_FIN_RECOVERABLE
    , NET_RENEWAL_COMMISSION
    , NON_UNIT_RESERVE_PP
    , NUR_CHANGE
    , PEN_FEE_INCOME
    , PEN_FEE_RATE_PC
    , PERSONAL_ACCIDENT_CHARGE
    , PERS_ACC_ACORN_COST
    , POLICY_FEE_INCOME
    , POLICY_VALUE
    , PREMIUM_INCOME
    , PREM_LEVY
    , PROFITABLE_BEL_EX_EXP
    , PROFITABLE_BEL_INCL_EXP
    , RENEWAL_COMMISSION
    , RENEWAL_COMM_CLAWBACK
    , RENEWAL_EXPENSE
    , SCOR_PART2_PREMIUM
    , Cast(NULL AS INT) AS SER3_BONUS_ALLOC
    , Cast(NULL AS INT) AS SER3_BONUS_FUND_EXP
    , Cast(NULL AS INT) AS SER3_BONUS_FUND_MC
    , Cast(NULL AS INT) AS SER3_NUR_RELEASE
    , Cast(NULL AS INT) AS SOLV_MARG_IF
    , SUMS_AT_RISK_IF
    , SUM_REINSURED
    , SURG_CASH_ACORN_COST
    , SURRENDER_PENALTY
    , TAX_RELIEF_EXPENSES
    , TOTAL_ACORN_COST
    , TOTAL_ACORN_COST_POLICIES_IN_DEBT
    , TOTAL_EXPENSE_AND_COMMISSION
    , TOTAL_EXPERIENCE_REFUND
    , TOTAL_REINSURANCE_CLAIMS
    , TOTAL_REINSURANCE_COST
    , TOTAL_RISK_CHARGES
    , TOT_EXPENSE
    , UNIT_LIABILITY_START
    , UNIT_RES_IF
    , V_POLICY_VALUE
    , WAIVER_ACORN_COST
    , WAIVER_CHARGE
    , WEIGHTED_INFORCE
    , WEIGHTED_INFORCE_MASS_LAPSE
FROM   [SII_%_U_FFIE_IMP]
```

Can you see now why I am keen to create a string for the column variables?

Comment: WHAT??? I assume with cross apply this is sql server and not mysql? It is not at all clear what you are trying to accomplish.

Comment: I'm unsure what command is necessary in this case. I thought CROSS APPLY but it has become evident that this in fact does not work. Sorry for any confusion caused

Comment: The confusion is in what you are trying to do. We don't know which DBMS you are using because you have tagged mysql and sq server. And it is not at all clear what you are trying to accomplish.

Comment: Here is a great place to start. http://spaghettidba.com/2015/04/24/how-to-post-a-t-sql-question-on-a-public-forum/

Comment: I'm using Microsoft SQL Server Management Studio.

Comment: @SeanLange  The OP wants a dynamic way of `union all`ing several tables that share some of the same columns, but not others.  In the example above, you can see 6 distinct columns (`A` through `F`) spread across the 3 `Product` tables.  OP wants all data in one big table, with blanks for where a column doesn't appear in the source table.

Comment: @C.McStay "Microsoft SQL Server Management Studio" is a client GUI not a DBMS. The DBMS it can connect to is Microsoft SQL Server. However ideally you should also specify the version of the server DBMS (_not_ the version of Management Studio!) as it can make a difference to what commands / SQL features are available.

Comment: SQL server 2014

Comment: Please format the code properly.  No one can/will read those code.

Comment: I don't see how this newly added wall of text relates to the desired output.

Answer (score 0):

You could write a SQL query that would dynamically create a SQL query that would union a select from the different tables, have them return NULL for columns they don't have. You can then execute the SQL query using `exec sp_executesql`

You can assemble a list of column for tables using T-SQL by querying `sys.tables` and `sys.columns`.

From that info you should have all you need to be able to figure out the set of all columns between all of the table and then which columns each table has and don't have.

You could then Use a cursor to iterate over the tables' columns and dynamically construct a query to UNION a select statement for each of the tables. Where each tables SELECT statement would select the value of the columns they do have, and `NULL AS 'someColumnName'` when the table doesn't contain the column of 'someColumnName'

Info on cursors can be found here: [Cursors for SQL Server](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/language-elements/declare-cursor-transact-sql)

Example of getting all columns on all tables using sys.tables and sys.columms:

```
SELECT 
    t.[object_id],
    t.[name],
    c.[name],
    c.[column_id]
FROM
    sys.tables AS t
INNER JOIN 
    sys.columns AS c ON (t.[object_id] = c.[object_id])
WHERE 
    t.[object_id] IN (OBJECT_ID(N'myTable1'),
                      OBJECT_ID(N'myTable2'),
                      OBJECT_ID(N'myTable3'))
ORDER BY 
    t.[object_id], c.column_id
```

Comment: This is very helpful however i want a code whereby i won't have to manually input the different tables as there are 65 + and the tables under consideration change over time.

Comment: Are they the only tables in the database?

Comment: no they only account for a small portion of tables in the database

Answer (score 0):

Most of this is just setup, but here's how I approached it.

First I built a table of the distinct columns across all the tables (the cte called `cols`. I then cross join that to a list of the tables (`#tables`) to get a set containing all possible combinations of column/table. I then left join that to `sys.columns` to see what columns ACTUALLY exist for those tables. If a given column doesnt exist for that table, the value from `sys.columns` will be null, and I can use that to differentiate what gets concatenated for my dynamic SQL (all this is in the cte `dsql`).

From there it's just a matter of serializing the data using `FOR XML` and `STUFF`. I chose to do this in two steps; first updating `#Tables` then doing a separate one to `union` everything together, but there's several ways to skin that cat.

```
use tempdb
go
set nocount on
go

-- Variable for Dynamic SQL
declare @sql nvarchar(max)

-- Setup some tables (need to be temp or real tables, not table vars, so there's schema info to pull
if object_id('tempdb.dbo.#Product1') is not null drop table #Product1
create table #Product1
(
    A int,
    C int,
    D int,
    F int
)

if object_id('tempdb.dbo.#Product2') is not null drop table #Product2
create table #Product2
(
    A int,
    B int,
    E int
)

if object_id('tempdb.dbo.#Product3') is not null drop table #Product3
create table #Product3
(
    B int,
    C int,
    D int,
    E int,
    F int,
)    

-- Populate sample data
insert into #Product1 (A, C, D, F) values(55, 100, 20, 40)
insert into #Product2 (A, B, E) values(78, 45, 21)
insert into #Product3 (B, C, D, E, F) values(101, 164, 24, 64, 56)


/*****************************
BEGIN WORK
*****************************/
-- Create a table with the distinct list of tables to consider
if object_id('tempdb.dbo.#Tables') is not null drop table #Tables
create table #Tables
(
    TableObjectId int primary key clustered,
    TableName nvarchar(128),
    ColumnList nvarchar(max)    
)

-- I just manually inserted these. You may need to gather these some other way 
insert into #Tables
(
    TableObjectId,
    TableName
)
select object_id('tempdb.dbo.#Product1'), '#Product1' union all
select object_id('tempdb.dbo.#Product2'), '#Product2' union all
select object_id('tempdb.dbo.#Product3'), '#Product3' 


-- Get a list of distinct columns across all the tables. Note, this assumess all the colums have the same data types
;with cols as
(
    select distinct name
    from sys.columns c
    inner join #Tables t
        on c.object_id = t.TableObjectId
-- I cross join the list of distinct columns to the list of distinct tables so there is a pairing for each table/column
-- I then join that set to the ACTUAL list of columns for each table. Note that ActualColumnname will be null if no such column exists
), dsql as
(
    select 
        SkellyColumnName = c.Name, 
        TableObjectId = t.TableObjectId, 
        TableName = t.TableName,
        ActualColumnName = c2.Name
    from cols c
    cross join #tables t
    left outer join sys.columns c2
        on t.TableObjectId = c2.object_id
            and c.name = c2.Name
)
-- Serialize the rows for DSQL. If the value is null, it will concatenate 'cast(null as int)'
update t
set ColumnList = stuff((select ',' + quotename(SkellyColumnName) + ' = ' + isnull(quotename(ActualColumnName), 'cast(null as int)')
                        from dsql d
                        where t.TableObjectId = d.TableObjectId
                        order by TableName, SkellyColumnName
                        for xml path('')), 1, 1, '')

from #Tables t

-- Do one more concatenation to union everything together
select @sql = stuff((select 'union all select ' + ColumnList + ' from ' + TableName + ' ' 
from #Tables
for xml path('')), 1, len('union all'), '')

-- Execute DSQL
 exec sp_executesql @sql
```

Result is:

```
A           B           C           D           E           F
----------- ----------- ----------- ----------- ----------- -----------
55          NULL        100         20          NULL        40
78          45          NULL        NULL        21          NULL
NULL        101         164         24          64          56
```